# Convert ArrayList of Integers to String Java

Tags: java

I want to convert an ArrayList of Integers to a single string.

For example:

```
List<Integers> listInt= new ArrayList();

String str = "";

listInt.add(1);
listInt.add(2);
listInt.add(3);

// I want the output to be: str = "123";
```

Comment: .... and your problem with your attempt is...?

Comment: `String s = "";
    for (int i : listInt)
        s += i;`

Comment: Please show your code attempt so we can see what you're doing wrong. Otherwise this is nothing but a terribly lazy "please do my work for me" question for trivial work at that.

Comment: @wvdz Creating N strings along the way is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Here's an interesting read for you: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: @wvdz Read it. The point there is: don't use string concatenation in loops, but don't go crazy about it. And the example is not about loops at all. I would still not recommend it to anybody, and that it's bad advice to give a novice.

Comment: I tried the following BEFORE I ask a question. String str = ""; for(int i =0; i<listInt.size();j++{
str = listIntget(i) + "";
}

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. And why do I have to prove to anybody that I tried or not? I have tried this with a lot of different ways that I cannot post here. And newbies dont get a lot of things as experienced developers do. So please be more polite and answer if you want without complaining. To just instruct me to write 3 rows of code (thats the complication of the problem) is far away from doing my work.

Comment: This is not a help site but rather a question and answer site. Why does this matter and how does it pertain to your question? It means that the quality of the question is just as important if not more important than the answers, since low quality questions will likely benefit no one in the future. Without your showing what you've done and without your asking a much more specific question, your question will remain low quality. That's why I am requesting that you strive to improve this question. I am hopeful that your future questions will be better.

Answer (score 0):

String numberString = listInt.stream().map(String::valueOf)
.collect(Collectors.joining(""));

//You can pass a delimiter if you want to the joining() function, like a comma. ","

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Declare list & varaible
    List<Integer> listInt= new ArrayList();
    String str = "";

    //add values into list
    listInt.add(1);
    listInt.add(2);
    listInt.add(3);
    //iterate list & add to append value to str
    for(Integer item:listInt){
        str+=item;
    }
    //print final output
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, the simplest way:

```
List<Integer> listInt = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
String str = "";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(Integer item : listInt)
  builder.append(item);
str = builder.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: What's wrong with my solution? I know it's a bad one, but it works, author didn't show any initiative so I won't write a perfect solution for him, this may at least motivate him to try further.